# How to completely remove Java 6 and install Java/JDK 7 on Linux Mint 13

Tags: linux-mint, java

How can I completely remove Java 6 and install Java/JDK 7 on Linux Mint 13?

Comment: Are you using the GUI or the Terminal?

Comment: Already answered below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how it's done:

```
# Must install 7 first or else when uninstalling six, it will try to install a bunch of replacement gcj stuff.
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre-lib
```

Afterwards:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```